# NGXS + Firestore or Firebase Auth

Tags: angular, ngxs

I saw that the NGXS state manager for Angular has released and i'm new to this topic. I'm trying to understand how do i connect the firestore or the firebase auth to NGXS but because it's so new i didn't find information anywhere
on the internet of how to do that, I will be glad if someone could explain me how to connect those. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used Firebase myself but maybe you could make use of the [NGXS + Firebase Demo](https://github.com/fisenkodv/itinerary) on [NGXS' resource page](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/community/resources). Or maybe you could get some usefull information from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13nWhUndQo4&t=) from Angular Firebase on how they use Firebase with NGRX (the framework that NGXS is based on).

Comment: I actually saw the video of Angular Firebase and also the demo from the resources but both of them didn't help me to understand that, If you know about other place i will be great, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I've started on a firebase example app, where I've got auth working.

Will shortly continue to get firestore working.

https://github.com/ngxs/ngxs-examples/blob/master/timekeeper/src/app/auth/auth.state.ts

But it is mostly calling angularfire2 and converting the results into actions.

Check out the link above to get a feel for it.

Comment: The links returns a 404.

Comment: the answer no longer has much value because the link is dead.